Non-trival Homomorphism from $\prod_{n \geq 2}{ \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}}$ to $\mathbb{Q}$
I'm trying to prove that $\text{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}}\left(\prod_{n \geq 2} I_n, \mathbb{Q}\right) \neq \bigoplus_{n \geq 2} \text{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}}(I_n, \mathbb{Q})$. The right hand side part is trivial module, so I need to construct a non-trivial element of the left hand side part. But it seems to me that there's no non-trivial map from $\prod_{n \geq 2}{ \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}}$ to $\mathbb{Q}$ as if it does exist, it would need to act non-trivially on infinitely many component of the product and produce a rational number. One way I'm trying to do is to establish some sort of convergent series to get rational number, however, nothing works so far.
Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks

$\mathbb{Q}$ is divisible, therefore injective. (See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisible_group .) As $\prod_{n \geq 2} \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ contains a copy of $\mathbb{Z}$, the embedding of $\mathbb{Z}$ into $\mathbb{Q}$ can be extended to a nontrivial homomorphism $\prod_{n \geq 2} \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Q}$.

Hi @David thanks for your answer. But I do not  get "product of Z/nZ contains a copy of Z"? and how does it extend to non trivial map to Q?

@the-only-cat-loving-philosophy The element $(1, 1, \cdots) \in \prod_{n \geq 2} \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ generates an infinite cyclic group, i.e., a copy of $\mathbb{Z}$. That it extends to a map defined on $\prod_{n \geq 2} \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ follows from the fact that $\mathbb{Q}$ is injective (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_object). The extended map is nontrivial because it is nontrivial on the copy of $\mathbb{Z}$ we started with.
